# 'fs' module not showing immediate effect, need to restart the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, fs

Its a NodeJS project. I am using `npm start` to start the server.

In this project, I am reading files of a folder `"./mydir/"` using `'fs.readdirSync'`, pushing files in an array and printing on console.

```
  var fs = require('fs');     
  var results= []; 
  var files = fs.readdirSync('./mydir/');
  for (var i in files) {
    results.push(files[i]); 
  }
  console.log(results);
```

Code is working fine and printing files of that directory on console.

But, while the server is on, when I am inserting/deleting a file (manually) from that directory `'./mydir/'` and refreshing the browser, it is not showing me the effects (pushes/prints the earlier result). I need to restart the server (`^C` then `npm start`) to see the changes in my browser.

Is there any way or any module to see the effects only by refreshing the browser (keeping the server running).

Comment: Your server reads the files once, not on every page load. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: Any other way using Node js modules ?

Comment: I'm sure there is a proper solution but we don't know what the actual problem you are trying to solve is.

Comment: Basically I am reading files of a server side folder, pushing it in array and, later, showing the list of files on UI.

Comment: If that list is expected to change, you might not want to cache it then, or limit how long it is cached for.

Comment: How to do so, will it show changes after every insert/delete a file ?

Comment: The simplest way would be to make the list anew for every page request that requires it, rather than once when the server starts. You will definitely want to avoid the `Sync`ronous functions though, to avoid blocking the queue while a request fetches the list.

Answer (score 0):

node.js servers are long running processes and variables scoped outside a given request last for the duration of the server process itself, they are not automatically created again for each request (like some other environments might do).

So, when you want updated results, you just have to run your code again.  You can put it in a function and call it whenever you want to update the results:

```
  var fs = require('fs');     

  function getFiles() {
      var results = []; 
      var files = fs.readdirSync('./mydir/');
      for (var i in files) {
        results.push(files[i]); 
      }
      console.log(results);
      return results;
  }
```

Then, you can call the function on your server anytime you want updated or refreshed results.

There is also the ability to watch for changes in the file system which could allow you to update your file listing automatically with [fs.watch()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher) by seeing changes as they occur and updating your cache at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You read the data once, print it and then seem to to nothing, at least if you don't have some other code in your server which repeats that snippet. But it wouldn't be a good idea to repeat reading the directory over and over again, because of efficiency.

You need to track the directory for changes and re-read it when some occur. There is a simple module out there which uses the mechanism of the OS to do this: [inotify](https://github.com/c4milo/node-inotify).

Your code could then look like that:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    Inotify = require('inotify').Inotify,
    inotify = new Inotify(),
    path = './mydir';

inotify.addWatch({
    path:      path,
    watch_for: Inotify.IN_CREATE | Inotify.IN_DELETE,
    callback:  function () {
        var results= []; 
        var files = fs.readdirSync(path);
        for (var i in files) {
             results.push(files[i]); 
        }
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After exploring, I found a Node js module `"forever"` which keeps my server running and track for any changes in the directory `"./mydir/"`.

I added it in `dependencies` of `"package.json"`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "forever": "^0.15.2"
  }
```

And added alias of `npm start` in `scripts` of `"package.json"` like this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "forever --watch --watchDirectory ./mydir  ./server.js"
 }
```

Optionally, commented the line `open(url)` in `"server.js"` to prevent opening browser after every change in `"./dir"`.

And it worked ! Now after any change in `"./dir"`, I refresh my browser when I want and it gives me the updated result.